# Indexing error: Unalignable boolean series

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting Indexing error in following code

```
data.loc[data.loc[sub_df_idx, 'A'] == data.loc[sub_df_idx, 'A'].min(), 'B']
```

sub_df_idx is just

```
Int64Index([25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
            42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
           dtype='int64')
```

The error is as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-166fca4d6d06> in <module>
----> 1 data.loc[data.loc[sub_df_idx, 'A'] == data.loc[sub_df_idx, 'A'].min(), 'B']

c:\users\hitesh vijay somani\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1760                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1761                     pass
-> 1762             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1763         else:
   1764             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

c:\users\hitesh vijay somani\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1287                 continue
   1288 
-> 1289             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
   1290 
   1291         return retval

c:\users\hitesh vijay somani\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1912             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1913         elif com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 1914             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1915         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
   1916 

c:\users\hitesh vijay somani\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getbool_axis(self, key, axis)
   1780         # caller is responsible for ensuring non-None axis
   1781         labels = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
-> 1782         key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
   1783         inds = key.nonzero()[0]
   1784         return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)

c:\users\hitesh vijay somani\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in check_bool_indexer(index, key)
   2315         mask = isna(result._values)
   2316         if mask.any():
-> 2317             raise IndexingError(
   2318                 "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
   2319                 "indexer (index of the boolean Series and of "

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: why do you have two `data.loc` on the left hand side of your equation? can you post your data the first two lines?

Comment: The boolean conditioncan only be checked in certain subset of the data. That is why I had to use `data.loc`  twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index of mask has to be same length like original, so compare original column `A` and then filter only index values from `sub_df_idx` by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
data.loc[(data['A'] == data.loc[sub_df_idx, 'A'].min()) & df.index.isin(sub_df_idx), 'B']
```

Or first filter rows by `sub_df_idx` and then by `min` values:

```
df = data.loc[sub_df_idx]
df.loc[df['A'] == df[ 'A'].min(),  'B']
```